# Set container to full width and not able to scroll horizontal on mobile device

Tags: jquery, html, css

Here is the test link:

http://kotechweb.com/ig112/

Right now on mobile device, 
is scroll to middle horizontally,

I would like to achieve is like this

[image]

the container is full width on the mobile and disable to scroll horizontally

Here is the code:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.5">
```

And scroll to middle

```
scrollTo(($(document).width() - $(window).width()) / 2, 0);
```

The background is set to 1903px as doesn't want the center content move left when resize the window

Thanks a lot for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing some things with your layout that will cause it to not work well responsively and the viewport measurements will probably be off (I don't have the proper device to test this but fixing these things should fix your problem):

1. Set initial scale to 1. Why do you have it set for .5? I imagine to compensate for your layout issues? Your static width for the content container won't allow it to be responsive which is probably what you're fighting against.
2. Set .my_box {
   max-width: 1903px;
   }
3. .my_box container inline style set to no-repeat, scroll, and center center, then use background-size: cover so it always fits:

background: transparent url("./assets/image/bg5.jpg") no-repeat scroll center center / cover;
    background-size: cover;
}

4. Then test your js and you will find scrolling is going to the proper place, 1/2 way down your page but you don't want this, you want it to scroll to an anchor. Put the anchor (hash/id) where you want the scroll to go then set your jQuery to zoom there after page load.

Let me know how this goes.

Comment: thanks wait a moment, yes the layout quite complex now and I don't mind dirty work

Comment: Your page is also huge in filesize, 5.5MB, make sure you compress your images.

Comment: thanks a lot! would you mind take a look at the class "prize_bg" ? I have some customize to that particular background, may be not apply to your css. Thanks

Comment: I appreciate your willingness to help @NathanielFlick as I fear a snowball effect of issues coming. As you pointed out there a number of issues with the way the OP has developed their site that will make it very difficult to work properly on mobile. Mainly because the content of the site is stuffed into a bunch of images and elements are overlaid.

Comment: As I'm looking further there are other images keeping the layout from going responsive (stops around 1200px wide or so). Make sure no containers have a min width or static width.

Comment: thanks for your effort, do you mean the container width 980px need to remove?

Comment: anyway have updated according to your pervious advice, please take a look

Comment: No there are still containers that aren't allowing the center container to shrink responsively. You'll need to check through each of them to find the culprits.

Comment: Hi I won't have time to fix all your code but all you have to do is make sure no containers are set to a static width = px. Good luck!